# how to make an regular expression in javascript to repeat

Tags: javascript, expression

How can I make it to validate this string:

```
word:word,word:word,
```

What I wrote this and works only for:

```
word:word,enithinggg
```

which is wrong.

```
/^(^([0-9a-zA-Z!\? ])+\:([0-9a-zA-Z!\?. ])+\,)+$/i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/^(([0-9a-zA-Z!\?])+\:([0-9a-zA-Z!\?])+\,?)+$/`

should do it.  You had `^` inside the first group, forcing it to match a newline.  I'm not too familiar with javascript regular expressions, so I'm not sure what the `i` at the end was doing.

You can run quick tests on http://rubular.com

Comment: The `i` means case-insensitive matching. With the flag set, you don't need `a-zA-z` in character classes, you can just use `a-z` or `A-Z`. Given that the OP uses `a-zA-Z` though, they might not know what it means either ;)